# ClassNotFound exception after adding external jar

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I'm adding an external `jar` to my `Eclipse` project. After running the programs which contain classes from `external jar` I'm getting a `ClassNotFound` exception for the classes from `external jar`. I have tried to change the export order and tried including it in run configurations. Still the error exists. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to add this jar in java build path

Comment: yes its added to buildpath

Comment: Single jar may have dependency on other jars, may be you are just adding a single jar but it might need other jars.

Comment: Add the exception trace and jar name you added on to your build path.

Comment: can you provide the jar file name?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the class names that you are using from jar files are correct. Java is a case-sensitive language and you might have mis-spelled the class names. Or you might have added the wrong jar file.

Also there is a chance that you might need to add multiple jar files since classes in one jar file may depend on some classess in other jar files.